# On Demand Permissions In Android

Tags: android, security, permissions

Is there a mechanism in Android where my app can prompt the user for specific permissions IF AND ONLY IF a particular app feature is ever used? For example, my app would never need access to the user's Contact List if the user does not want to share his activities with his Contacts. So I do not want to ask for these permissions upfront in the manifest file and possibly reduce the # app installs. Facebook SDK allows On Demand permissions (only ask for permissions IF and WHEN needed). I need the same exact behavior for Android permissions within my app.

Comment: Not sure which moron downvoted this question because it's a legitimate programming question on Android!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all permissions need to be specified in the manifest file and the user will see and need to accept these permissions when he installs your app. The difference with the facebook sdk is that these permissions don't relate to the device itself, but to the facebook account it links to.

EDIT: Since Marshmallow you can request permissions at run time, but only for devices running marshmallow. You can check how to do this here:
[Android Developers Page](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Since Marshmallow you can request permissions at run time. But it is possible to ask persmission only before the user will need the feature to avoid requesting every user at the first launch ?